# Does mounting external media read only make ejecting the media unnessesary? If so, how to mount all external media read only?

Tags: linux, readonly, removable-storage

I am building hardware solutions for video debriefing purposes, where users will connect and remove cameras and/or SD cards to computers all the time. 
I am working with Raspberry pi's (Raspbian) for media playback.
A fast media server for video related calculations and media conversion (Ubuntu) and a fast NAS for storage. 
I like to overcome the need for the user to ejecting media before removing the hardware, because I know from experience nobody will take the effort anyway. I have no need for my system to write data onto the users devices. So I was wondering if there is a way to mount all external devices always read-only in order to prevent any data corruption on unsafe removal.

I am fairly new to Linux and programming. The software I am writing is mainly Python, but I am looking for a more system wide approach for this problem so the user will not experience any

Answer (score 1):

It's always recommended to umount properly any media , a file can still be opened for example

You can force media to mount read only with mount command options dedicated to options

```
mount -o ro /dev/media /example/path
```

you can use udev rules to force this option to any external media ... see this post to know how to [How can I create a udev rule to mount a USB drive read only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119853/how-can-i-create-a-udev-rule-to-mount-a-usb-drive-read-only)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Do you know if mounting read only really means the data on the mounted drive is not touched in any way? or can a file still become corrupt if its opened while a the drive is removed?

Comment: risk is nearly zero ...

Comment: Data on the external media should stay untouched.  But the running system can become unstable after that, especially if you're disconnecting a (spinning) disk.

Comment: @SatōKatsura No it can’t. Never happens. And besides rpi up to revision 2 can’t source enough current to drive a magnetic disk. GNU/Linux is famous for ignoring conditions that would make a sane operating system panic (...and so is Linus Torvalds, but that’s off-topic)