# How to mount a particular USB drive read-only

Tags: udev

I have a requirement to mount certain USB drives read-only - not every drive, just those containing archived data. I want to prevent accidental or malicious changes.

There has been much written about `udev` and it seems to be possible, but my rules don't appear to be executed. I have studied [How can I create a udev rule to mount a USB drive read only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119853/321108) - I don't have gvfs and the other answers don't help.

Here’s my `/etc/udev/rules.d/25-usb-read-only.rules` file. For testing, I am using a drive with the volume name SCRATCH. The drive is mounted at /dev/sda but is always writable.

```
#SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="SCRATCH", ENV{UDISKS_MOUNT_OPTIONS}="ro"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="SCRATCH", MODE="0550"
#SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="SCRATCH", ENV{UDISKS_MOUNT_OPTIONS}="ro"
# The RUN here just to test the rule is executed
#KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="SCRATCH", RUN+="/home/test-udev.sh"
```

Comment-out lines are previous failed attempts. I have remembered `sudo udevadm control --reload` between tests.

Note that even the RUN command failed. The script only writes a debug file, and works when executed from the command line.

I have enabled debug and examined `/var/log/syslog` – there are tens of thousands of lines just for the few seconds of a test. I could find nothing helpful.

My system is Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon, but all of the above was from bash.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original (pre-`systemd`) implementation of `udev` turned out to be too powerful: it introduced race conditions and other security issues. As a result, modern `systemd-udevd` is more locked down than its predecessors, and cannot do all the same things the older versions did. There is a lot of information on how to mount removable disks using older `udev`, but the current recommendation is that **you should not do that**, and `udevd` sandboxing and other security restrictions implemented in newer distributions are actually making it increasingly more difficult or impractical to do.

The current understanding is essentially that `udev`'s **primary** job is to create and manage the device nodes in a timely manner with appropriate ownerships and permissions, and **optionally** provide some additional metadata on the device nodes for the other services to use; anything else that might compromise the primary job should be avoided. So, anything that would cause `udev` to start long-running processes is right out.

Mounting a filesystem can take an arbitrarily long time, especially if the filesystem is large or corrupted, and so `udevd` should be leaving that to other services like `udisks2` instead of doing it directly.

If Mint 21.1 has `udisks2` version 2.9.0 or later (package name might be `libudisks2-0` since there used to be another `udisks` implementation before the current one), the `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` would be a better place to do it.

You could do something like this:

```
[/dev/disk/by-label/SCRATCH]
defaults=ro
# removed "rw" from the global default list of allowed mount options
allow=exec,noexec,nodev,nosuid,atime,noatime,nodiratime,ro,sync,dirsync,noload
```

This document on `mount_options.conf` includes a number of examples, including example udev rules for matching a particular USB storage device by device serial number, which is more secure than using the filesystem label like you wanted:
http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/mount_options.html

Normally, removable media devices get a `TAG+="uaccess"` udev rule, which gives locally-logged-in user(s) write access to the devices. This means they automatically have all the privileges needed to change the filesystem labels on any removable media device. That means your proposed strategy of using filesystem label to protect against malicious changes can be trivially worked around, and is not secure.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like good advice. It explains why I got so confused in my reading about udev. I DO have udisks (v.2.9.4), and I will study it later.

Comment: The first suggestion `[/dev/disk/by-label/SCRATCH]` did just what I want. I am still considering the security implications.